# Flutter Firebase MacOS cloud_firestore/unavailable

Tags: flutter, firebase

I'm trying to setup firebase for my flutter macos app. I followed the steps in the setup guide, meaning I have done:

1. Created the macos platform with `flutter create .`
2. flutterfire configure --project=PROJECT_NAME --platforms=macos
3. Initialize the app with

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

The `flutterfire configure` command created the macos app in my Firebase project and I made sure it uses the correct Bundle Id.

However my documents from firestore are not loading and I get the following error

> Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff.

I'm using the latest firebase package versions. Nothing I have tried works so far.

What could this error mean? All I found so far was [this](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/discussions/5708), but this describes only a offline issue, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You should do Firestore rules like this ->

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: My permissions are not the problem. Furthermore, there is a different error for no permission

Comment: Are you sure that using latest versions of flutter and firebase ? Unless it works, you may create a new test project then try again.